# With an Arduino how do I use an RFID reader, stepper motor and switch to toggle the state of the stepper?

Tags: arduino, rfid, stepper

I'm trying to toggle the use of a stepper motor using a button and an RFID reader. Both work in isolation but when I try and use them both together it doesn't work. The stepper shudders and the RFID tags can't be read. I'm thinking I'll need to do something to make sure the RFID tags are programmed and read before going any further.

It seems to be when checking if an RFID card is present is when it causes problems.

I've narrowed it down a little, it breaks on this line:

`if (readRFID() == true) {`

and these lines:

```
   if (isTagPresent()==true){
      getTagID();
      checkTagID();
   } else {
    //delay(10);
    //return
   }
```

Here's the entire sketch:

```
/*
  Debounce

  Each time the input pin goes from LOW to HIGH (e.g. because of a push-button
  press), the output pin is toggled from LOW to HIGH or HIGH to LOW. There's a
  minimum delay between toggles to debounce the circuit (i.e. to ignore noise).

  The circuit:
  - LED attached from pin 13 to ground through 220 ohm resistor
  - pushbutton attached from pin 2 to +5V
  - 10 kilohm resistor attached from pin 2 to ground

  - Note: On most Arduino boards, there is already an LED on the board connected
    to pin 13, so you don't need any extra components for this example.

  created 21 Nov 2006
  by David A. Mellis
  modified 30 Aug 2011
  by Limor Fried
  modified 28 Dec 2012
  by Mike Walters
  modified 30 Aug 2016
  by Arturo Guadalupi

  This example code is in the public domain.

  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Debounce
*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
// Include the AccelStepper library:
#include <AccelStepper.h>


   // Other hardware pins
    const byte rstPin =  39;                // Reset pin
    const byte  ssPin = 53;                // Slave Select pin


// Define stepper motor connections and motor interface type. Motor interface type must be set to 1 when using a driver:
#define dirPin 2
#define stepPin 3
#define motorInterfaceType 1



// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 45;  // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin = 27;    // the number of the LED pin

// Define Pins
#define BLUE 25
#define GREEN 23
#define RED 27

// Variables will change:
int ledState = HIGH;        // the current state of the output pin
int buttonState;            // the current reading from the input pin
int lastButtonState = LOW;  // the previous reading from the input pin

// the following variables are unsigned longs because the time, measured in
// milliseconds, will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers

const long timeout = 30000;            // Timeout in ms 

// Create a new instance of the AccelStepper class:
AccelStepper stepper = AccelStepper(motorInterfaceType, stepPin, dirPin);

    // Instantiate MFRC522 object class
    MFRC522 rfidReader(ssPin, rstPin);

    char* myTags[100] = {};
    int tagsCount = 0;
    String tagID = "";

bool readRFID(long _timeout=timeout, bool useTimeout=false){

    /*  readRFID will continuously check the RFID reader for the presence of
     *    a tag from and will attempt to get tag IDs. Updates global value
     *    tagID via getTagID function.
     *  Parameters:
     *    _timeout   - [optional] the length of time before functio gives up
     *                 default value = global timout value
     *    useTimeout - [optional] boolean to enforce timout period or wait 
     *                 indefinately.  Default value = false.
     *  Returns:
     *    true  -  successfully reads tag ID
     *    false -  unsuccessful in reading the tag ID          
     */
    bool successRead = false;

    unsigned long startTime = millis();
    unsigned long currentTime = startTime;
    // S'U'+S'T'
    // T  = (currentTime-startTime) > timeout
    // T' = (currentTime-startTime) < timeout
    while (((successRead==false)&&(useTimeout==false)) || ((successRead==false)&&((currentTime - startTime) < _timeout))) {    
        if (isTagPresent() == true){ successRead = getTagID(); }
        currentTime = millis();
    }
    return successRead;
}



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 


    SPI.begin();                            // Start SPI bus
    rfidReader.PCD_Init();                  // Start MFRC522 object

    while (!Serial);                        // Do nothing if no serial port is opened
    
    // Obviously this is an over simplified sketch
    // Master tags would be save in flash storage and
    // retrieved here.  OR a special PIN entered to set
    // Master Tag.
    // But for the sake of simplicity, the sketch will 
    // obtain a new master tag when restarted.
    
    // Prints the initial message
    Serial.println(F("-No Master Tag!-"));
    Serial.println(F("    SCAN NOW"));

    // readRFID will wait until a master card is scanned
    /*
    if (readRFID() == true) {
      Serial.println("Reading tag");
        myTags[tagsCount] = strdup(tagID.c_str()); // Sets the master tag into position 0 in the array
        Serial.println(F("Master Tag is Set!"));
        tagsCount++;
    }
    printNormalModeMessage();
    */
    
  // Set the maximum speed in steps per second:
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  //pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
    //pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
    //digitalWrite(BLUE, LOW);

}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the switch into a local variable:
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check to see if you just pressed the button
  // (i.e. the input went from LOW to HIGH), and you've waited long enough
  // since the last press to ignore any noise:

  // If the switch changed, due to noise or pressing:
  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer than the debounce
    // delay, so take it as the actual current state:

    // if the button state has changed:
    if (reading != buttonState) {
      buttonState = reading;

      // only toggle the LED if the new button state is HIGH
      if (buttonState == LOW) {
          ledState = !ledState;
          toggleLock(ledState);
          digitalWrite(RED, !digitalRead(RED)); // toggle the output
          digitalWrite(GREEN, !digitalRead(GREEN)); // toggle the output
      }
    }
  }

  // set the LED:
  //digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);

  // save the reading. Next time through the loop, it'll be the lastButtonState:
  lastButtonState = reading;


/*
  if (isTagPresent()==true){
      getTagID();
      checkTagID();
  } else {
    //delay(10);
    //return
  }
*/ 


}

void toggleLock(int ledState){
 
  if(ledState == HIGH){
    // Reset the position to 0:
    stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);

    // Run the motor backwards at 600 steps/second until the motor reaches -200 steps (1 revolution):
    while(stepper.currentPosition() != -100) 
    {
      stepper.setSpeed(-600);
      stepper.runSpeed();
    }

  } else {
    // Reset the position to 0:
    stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);

    // Run the motor forward at 400 steps/second until the motor reaches 600 steps (3 revolutions):
    while(stepper.currentPosition() != 100)
    {
      stepper.setSpeed(400);
      stepper.runSpeed();
    }
  }
  //return 1;
}


/* ***********************************************************
 *                         Functions                         *
 * ********************************************************* */
bool isTagPresent(){
    /*  isTagPresent uses the MFRC522 methods to determine if 
     *    a tag is present or the read card serial is enabled.
     *  Parameters: (none)
     *  Returns:
     *    true  - if tag detected or read card serial is true
     *    false - no tag detected or no read card serial true
     */     
    bool returnValue = true;
    
    // NOT a new PICC_IsNewCardPresent in RFID reader
    //OR
    // NOT a PICC_ReadCardSerial active in Serial
    if ( !rfidReader.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() || !rfidReader.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) { 
      returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}

byte checkMyTags(String tagID){
    /* checkMyTags function loops through the array of myTags
     *   Parameters:
     *     tagID    - a string to look for
     *   Returns:
     *     tagIndex - index in the array of myTags
     *                default 0     
     */
    byte tagIndex = 0;
    //Serial.println("checkMyTags Started");
    // Zero is reserved for master tag
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        if (tagID == myTags[i]) { tagIndex = i; }
    }
    //Serial.println("checkMyTags ended");
    return tagIndex;
}

void checkTagID(){
    /* checkTagID check the tag ID for authorized tag ID values
     *   if Master tag found switch to program mode
     * Parameters: (none)
     * Returns: (none)
     */
    // Checks for Master tag
    if (tagID == myTags[0]) {
        // Switch to program mode
        Serial.println(F(" Program mode:"));
        Serial.println(F(" Add/Remove Tag"));
        
        // Now with timeout
        // readRFID will skip if timeout exceeded
       // if (readRFID(timeout,true)==true) {
          if (readRFID()==true) {
            //Check for authorized tag
            byte tagIndex = checkMyTags(tagID);
            if (tagIndex!=0){
                //Remove existing tag
                myTags[tagIndex] = '\0';
                Serial.println(F("  Tag Removed!"));
            } else {
                //Not existing, add tag
                myTags[tagsCount] = strdup(tagID.c_str());
                Serial.println(F("  Tag Added!"));
                tagsCount++;
            }
        } else {
            Serial.println(F("    timeout"));
        }
    } else { 
        //Check for authorized tag
        byte tagIndex = checkMyTags(tagID);
        if (tagIndex!=0){
            //Authorized tag
            Serial.println(F(" Access Granted!"));
            //unlock();
        } else {
            //Not authorized tag
            //lock();
            Serial.println(F(" Access Denied!"));
            Serial.println(F(" New UID & Contents:"));
            rfidReader.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(rfidReader.uid));
        }
    }
    printNormalModeMessage();
}

bool getTagID() {
    /*  getTagID retrieves the tag ID.  Modifies global variable tagID
     *           
     *    Parameters: (none)    
     *    Returns: true
     */

    tagID = "";
    
    Serial.print(F(" UID tag: "));
    for (byte i = 0; i < rfidReader.uid.size; i++){
        // The MIFARE PICCs that we use have 4 byte UID
        Serial.print(rfidReader.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
        Serial.print(rfidReader.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
        // Adds the bytes in a single String variable
        tagID.concat(String(rfidReader.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
        tagID.concat(String(rfidReader.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    tagID.toUpperCase();
    rfidReader.PICC_HaltA();                     // Stop reading
    return true;
}

void printNormalModeMessage() {
    /*  printNormalModeMessage sends the standard greeting
     *    to the serial monitor.
     *  Parameters: (none)
     *  Returns: (none)
     */
   // delay(1500);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println(F("-Access Control-"));
    Serial.println(F(" Scan Your Tag!"));
}
```